# How can I construct a bar chart using plt function

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I did a web scrape on ps4 games and I wanted to construct a bar chart using label x as the product_name variable I have and label y as the price variable I have. And another pie chart of the cheapest ps4 games using my price variable to determine how much percent out of 100 this 5 brands (all found under my brand variable.): playstation, Ubisoft, Activision, Sega, and electronic arts, represent in my data. so the pie chart would have the name and percent of each brand and the rest of the percent would be labels "others".
any hints how can I start.

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

url='https://www.newegg.com/PS4-Video-Games/SubCategory/ID-3141'

with uReq(url) as uClient:
    page = uClient.read()

# parsing
page_soup = soup(page, "html.parser")

# grabs products
containers= page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item-container"})

# save to file
filename = "products.csv"


#creating two empty dictionaries
d = defaultdict(list)
d1 = defaultdict(list)

# for loop fills dict
for container in containers:
    #brand name
    brand = container.div.div.a.img["title"]

    #product name
    title = container.findAll("a", {"class":"item-title"})
    product_name = title[0].text

    #shipping 
    shipping_container = container.findAll("li", {"class":"price-ship"})
    shipping = shipping_container[0].text.strip()
    
    #price column
    pricec = container.find("li", {"class":"price-current"})
    #removing all white spaces
    price= pricec.text.strip('price-current')
    
    d['Product'].append(product_name)
    d['shipping'].append(shipping)
    d1['Product'].append(product_name)
    d1['Brand'].append(brand)
    d1['price'].append(price)
    
    
# create dataframe    
df = pd.DataFrame(d) #product and shipping
df1 =pd.DataFrame(d1) #product and brand 


# clean shipping column
df['shipping'] = df['shipping'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x == 'Free Shipping' else x)
#cleaning price column
df1['price'] = df1['price'].str.extract('(\d+\.?\d+)').astype(float)
#string converted to float
df['shipping'] = df['shipping'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x == 'Special Shipping' else x) # probably should be handled in a special way
df['shipping'] = df['shipping'].apply(lambda x: x if x == 0 else re.sub("[^0-9]", "", x))
df['shipping'] = df['shipping'].astype(float)

# save dataframe to csv file
df.to_csv('dataframe.csv', index=False)
df1.to_csv('dataframe1.csv', index=False)


df2 = pd.merge(df,df1, how ='inner') #pandas and merge data frames
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
import re

url='https://www.newegg.com/PS4-Video-Games/SubCategory/ID-3141'

with uReq(url) as uClient:
    page = uClient.read()

# parsing
page_soup = soup(page, "html.parser")

# grabs products
containers= page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item-container"})

# save to file
filename = "products.csv"


#creating two empty dictionaries
d = defaultdict(list)
d1 = defaultdict(list)

# for loop fills dict
for container in containers:
    #brand name
    brand = container.div.div.a.img["title"]

    #product name
    title = container.findAll("a", {"class":"item-title"})
    product_name = title[0].text

    #shipping 
    shipping_container = container.findAll("li", {"class":"price-ship"})
    shipping = shipping_container[0].text.strip()
    
    #price column
    pricec = container.find("li", {"class":"price-current"})
    #removing all white spaces
    price= pricec.text.strip('price-current')
    
    d['Product'].append(product_name)
    d['shipping'].append(shipping)
    d1['Product'].append(product_name)
    d1['Brand'].append(brand)
    d1['price'].append(price)
    
    
# create dataframe    
df = pd.DataFrame(d) #product and shipping
df1 =pd.DataFrame(d1) #product and brand 


# clean shipping column
df['shipping'] = df['shipping'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x == 'Free Shipping' else x)
#cleaning price column
df1['price'] = df1['price'].str.extract('(\d+\.?\d+)').astype(float)
#string converted to float
df['shipping'] = df['shipping'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x == 'Special Shipping' else x) # probably should be handled in a special way
df['shipping'] = df['shipping'].apply(lambda x: x if x == 0 else re.sub("[^0-9]", "", x))
df['shipping'] = df['shipping'].astype(float)

# save dataframe to csv file
df.to_csv('dataframe.csv', index=False)
df1.to_csv('dataframe1.csv', index=False)


df2 = pd.merge(df,df1, how ='inner') #pandas and merge data frames



plt.bar(brand, product_name, color='blue')
plt.xlabel("Product")
plt.ylabel("Prince")
plt.title("PopularitY of Programming Language\n" + "Worldwide, Oct 2017 compared to a year ago")
plt.xticks(brand, product_name)
# Turn on the grid
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.grid(which='major', linestyle='-', linewidth='0.5', color='red')
# Customize the minor grid
plt.grid(which='minor', linestyle=':', linewidth='0.5', color='black')
plt.show()```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the dataframe you saved as as `dataframe1.csv` in your code.

The bar graph is straight forward. The first 2 arguments of `plt.bar()` are the product names and price.

The pie chart is a little bit more tricky. You need to to manipulate the dataframe so you only have 6 rows (your 5 chosen brands, and then "other"), and create another column with the calculated percentage.

Refer to the matplotlib documentation and online tutorials to make it all look pretty.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = pd.read_csv('dataframe1.csv')

plt.bar(df1.Product, df1.price)
plt.title("Game prices")
plt.xlabel("Product name")
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.ylabel("Price ($)")
plt.show()

top5 = ["PlayStation", "Ubisoft", "Electronic Arts", "Activision", "Sega"]

# Change all the other brands to "other"
df1.loc[~df1.Brand.isin(top5), "Brand"] = "others"

# Change every price so each brand has its own total
df1.price = df1.groupby("Brand").price.transform("sum")

# Remove duplicates from the Brand column so we can easily calculate percentages
df1 = df1.drop_duplicates(subset="Brand")

# Create a new Percentage column for the percentages
df1["Percentage"] = df1.price / df1.price.sum() * 100

plt.pie(df1.Percentage, labels=df1.Brand, autopct="%1.2f%%")
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Bar graph and pie chart]